# Python calling functions from a if statement

Tags: python, function, integer

I want to sum up the numbers taken by `raw_input(">")` but instead of giving me the sum when I run the code on the python shell, it gives me the numbers paired. That would be: if I give 4 to `answer` and 5 to `answer2` on the input, it will return 45 instead of 9. Please help me.

```
from sys import argv

def sum(num1, num2):
    result =(num1 + num2)
    return result


print ' I wanna know your two results'
answer = raw_input(">")
answer2 = raw_input(">")

real_answer = sum(answer, answer2)
print real_answer
```

Comment: Could you please explain the title of your question?

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert to integers first:

```
answer = int(raw_input(">"))
answer2 = int(raw_input(">"))
```

or keep them the same and do this:

```
real_answer = sum(map(int, (answer, answer2)))
```

or

```
real_answer = sum(int(answer), int(answer2))
```

With only two numbers, though, you don't need `sum()`:

```
real_answer = int(answer) + int(answer2)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because the answers are being read as strings, and for strings the addition operator concatenates them.  You can fix it by changing the input lines to:

```
answer = int(raw_input(">"))
answer2 = int(raw_input(">"))
```

This converts the strings to integers before assigning them to `answer` and `answer2`.

If you want to support floating point numbers (e.g. `1.2`), change the `int` to `float`.